# Canadian Questrade margin account question

Tags: stocks, canada, margin, questrade

I have a Questrade margin account. I had more than enough cash and in error bought US stocks. I wasn't paying attention to my figures just whether I made money.

Once I saw the interest payments being taken out, I sold all the US stocks. I appear to be in the red by (-$7000.00) .

Since I sold all the US stocks and I am still being charged interest, what is going on? I should have about $10,000.00 in cash but the (-$7,000.00) is debiting my cash account. I did not agree to any loan. I began with all cash and even though lost on some stocks, I still made quite a bit.

How are US stocks still penalizing me if I sold them? Doesn't Questrade automatically take their money like their fees?

Comment: Have you talked to Questrade support? They can likely explain this to you.

Comment: Sometimes brokers keep currency positions separate, so you could be long CAD but short USD and still have to pay interest until you specifically buy some USD with your CAD to pay your margin balance.